# Autoclick cells with references

Tags: excel

I have an excel where I have a column called roles with text like:

[image]

Then I have another column where I have name and reference this first column like:

[image]

My question is, there is a way to assign first column to second one, I.E: if I click on `GetSalesOrderItems = 1,2,4,5` cell, autoclick cells 1,2,4 and 5? is that possible? How can I do a reference of second column to first column? Regards

Comment: What do you mean "Autoclicks cells". What do you mean by "Reference" here. Can you explain more about what you are trying to do/what you want to happen?

Comment: For example if you have a formula of some column like : `=SUM(G9:G12)` if you double clic that column, it automatically select columns that are in sum function, I want to do exactly the same but reference cell @JNevill

Comment: OK. I think I understand. I doubt you can replicate exactly that functionality, but probably close with VBA. In the case where the cell is `GetSalesOrderITems=1,2,4,5` given your first column, which cells would be highlighted there (I'm guessing `Manager=1`, `Vendor=2`, and `Shop=4` and there is no `5`). Is that right?

Comment: Yes you're right, and I miss item 5... just guessing it exist @JNevill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of doing something like this in VBA.

Assuming you have a sheet like:

[image]

You can add code to the sheet (open your VBE, double click the worksheet in the Project pane and paste in this code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick() fires whenever a double click is detected on this worksheet.

    'Our thing being double clicked is in B1, so lets make sure the double click came from there by testing `Target`
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then

        'Must be B1... so let's load the numbers into an array
        Dim numArray As Variant
        numArray = Split(Split(Target, "=")(1), ",")

        'We are going to assume we already have some highlighted cells. Unhighlight this first
        i = 1
        Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
            Cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = False
            'increment for the next loop
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        'Now we can loop this array and search for it in Column A
        For Each num In numArray

            'Loop through column A
            i = 1
            Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
                'test if it shares a value
                If num = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, "=")(1) Then
                    'Make the cell bold or something
                    Cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
                End If
                'increment for the next loop
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        Next num

    End If

End Sub
```

That's going to bold any cells in Column A that share a value of the cell in Column B (When you double click on that cell).

No doubt you will need to edit this to get what you need, but this should get you in the ballpark.